# Product and Description with different name in odoo

Tags: odoo, product, quotations

How can you make products and descriptions name different from each other? The picture below has the same names. 
[image]

I cannot edit it in products.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to overwrite the **name_get** function of a **product.product** the object for this. You Can check the sample,

```
class ProductProductInherit(models.Model):
_inherit = 'product.product'

def name_get(self):
    res = super(ProductProductInherit, self).name_get()
    # write the code to here
    # then you can return the product name
    return res
```

Thanks